# I use sendmany to make bitcoin payments

Tags: bitcoind

[image]

this my php code.
but the result returned is false!
How can i do it?

I want to pay more bitcoin at a time.

Comment: Does it work if you use `sendtoaddress` instead?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you don't need to encode the array. 
The library you are using should take care of this for you - at least the EasyBitcoin library does.

Let us know